# How to convert string to YAML in Ruby 2.3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using delayed_job in my  application and I am showing some info about the jobs.
I am ability show the id and priority attributes where I couldn't show the handler details.

In my view, when I try to view details of the job:

```
<% @jobs.each do |item| %>   
  <% obj = YAML.load(item.to_yaml) %>
  <%= obj.inspect %> 
<% end %>
```

when I use inspect, I am getting details as:

```
#<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 51, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer\nobject...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2016-08-25 19:56:44", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, created_at: "2016-08-25 19:56:44", updated_at: "2016-08-25 19:56:44", queue: nil>
```

Now I need to get method_name from handler, for this, inorder to list the details, I used

```
 <%= obj.handler.inspect %>
```

It gave:

> "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer\nobject: !ruby/class
>   'SubscriptionNotifier'\nmethod_name: :welcome\nargs:\n-
>   !ruby/object:User\n raw_attributes:\n deleted_at: \n name: ESPN STAR\n
>   email: esp@test.com\n encrypted_password:
>   \"$2a$10$jlV1bljCXpto4iTHnkKVnOzE.Us6lmGDtkUVdniw4DFTk8vzkX1oS\"\n
>   phone: ''\n website: ''\n designations: ''\n id: 22\n
>   reset_password_token: \n reset_password_sent_at: \n
>   remember_created_at: \n sign_in_count: '0'\n  so on

For showing method_name, I think we should make above string yaml, for this I tried:

```
 <% obj = YAML.load(item.handler.to_yaml) %>
```

No luck. Please help me how can I convert to yaml or how can I show this method_name?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <%= YAML.load(job.handler)["method_name"] %> 
<% end %>
```

As in `job.handler` the yaml is saved, you can parse this and then access the `method_name` with [].

Comment: It is showing error as `undefined class/module` with some Psych content in the log.

Comment: In my previous Rails 3.2 version, it was working fine as I simply used `<% obj = YAML.load(item.handler) %>` and called `<%= obj.method_name %>`. But here in Rails 4.2 I am getting undefined class/module error.

Comment: This is because the YAML tries to automatically initialise a ruby object from the yaml data. `Object.new.to_yaml
=> "--- !ruby/object {}\n"` So make sure that you have `Delayed` (class/module) available.

Comment: How can I make this Delayed (class/module) available